# Jest: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, jestjs, babel-jest

This is a very simple alteration of the jest tutorial example for react DOM unit testing. I have a counter component and I want to test that it works. You can see my commit at the bottom.

Error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

There's only 2 { in the .test.js file and when I remove the `jsx ={1}` replacing it with ="1" , it doesn't remove the error. The other { is in the function call `() => {`

**Update 1 (Response to Answer)**

I have changed the .test.js file to test.tsx , and made a change to the counter component to allow strings removing the jsx {} and the only other `{` besides the function constructor.

https://github.com/Falieson/react15-meteor1.5-typescript2.4/commit/36a327e79700b5532258f7fb8a171122ed260329

**Update 2**

I've discovered through trying to expose this issue that this error is only happening on my work machine, and not my personal developer machine. Here's the code that works on my machine but not on my work machine.
https://github.com/Falieson/react-typescript-meteor

**Update 3**
I don't get any problems from jest when I run `npm run test:jest` but when I run `meteor npm run test:jest` I get this issue, going to go ask on the [meteor boards](https://forums.meteor.com/t/-meteor--npm-run-causes-jest-syntax-error/38506/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else coming across this question I would recommend updating Meteor to the latest 1.6-beta* so you get Node 8 rather than relying on Node 4. As discussed in the meteor forum thread linked in the OP, node 4 is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are `js` files that are importing typescript `ts` files. According to your config you have

`'^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'`

Which I guess will use the babel-jest parser instead of the typescript compiler. You will have to write your tests as `ts` files and let typescript do its magic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I think you're right that it needs to be a .ts/.tsx file instead but that still doesn't fix the issue! Question updated w/ new commit